# how to make the on off button in lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I want to find such a code so that I insert my script there, for example, in this format

```lua
loadstring(Game:Http Get("https://pastebin.com/raw/0A4J7V8M "))()
```

Iii so that it works and there is a button to turn on and off
I have a script I made it using YouTube, but I don't understand how to make the code to turn the script off and on by clicking in the menu
And yes I wanted to say I have a script menu where I have already added several scripts, I need code so that I can add a script link there and so that it can be disabled and enabled through the menu

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking, mainly because you haven't told us what platform you're using Lua on. (You're clearly not referring to vanilla Lua.) Please add a tag indicating the platform, plus some code to show an example of what you've already tried.

Comment: All of the code in the loadstring is encoded. And most of it isn't in English

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring to the Roblox API, you'd want to use a TextButton.

```lua
TextButton.MouseButton1Up:Connect(function()
    loadstring(game:HttpGet("https://pastebin.com/raw/0A4J7V8M"))()
end)
```